# Having problems with UI Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

This always happens when I make a UI in Unity:

I make a UI like this:
[image: Making UI]

But in game I see it like this:
[image: Previewing UI]

I tried to change the aspect but the same thing happens. Also I want to still be in Free Aspect. I there anyway to fix it?

Comment: try changing the "rect transform" (i dont know what it is called Im kinda new to unity) by clicking the icon beside it and fix it to the top left hand side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the direction of the Anchor and also the location of the pivot, so as not to make mistakes in the different dimensions of the resulotion. To facilitate the work, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> while specifying the anchor and simultaneously select the left corner.

[image: Shift]

Comment: It worked! thanks! im kinda new to unity